# JSF2 loadbundle issue

Tags: jsf-2

Trying to design a facelet using Mojarra tags.In base template trying to load the property file using loadBundle tag.During runtime getting error like below

```
Can't find resouce for bundle web/test/properties/sample key en_GB
```

Placed the property file in the below location
`webapp/test/properties/sample.properties` and adding this like below

```
   <f:loadBundle basename="test.properties.sample" var="msgs" />
```

Also I tried to place the property file under `webapp/resources/test/properties/sample.properties` but no hopes.

Could anyone please throw some light to resolve the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to be using the Maven structure, is this true? Please add Maven tag accordingly to get attention from the right guys. In standard structure, you just have to put it in `src` folder exactly like as you would put your Java classes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the resource bundle should be in the src folder. But you can find here a detailed example about resource bundles: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-and-resource-bundles-example/

I hope it helps!